# my review of the proposed 'honeypot' tag

Tags: discussion, tags, reviewing

as can seen here:

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/honeypot/info

I have rejected on the grounds that this tag will be deleted soon.

I am wondering whether this is the general consensus?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Where can we review a tag and reject it, and what would you like to know is/isn't the general consensus?

Comment: If you meant [this review](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/31740), I believe that "honeypot" is ambiguous, and needs clarification, and even though I don't think the tag will stay for long I think it would be good for confused users to be able to see what the tag is about.

Comment: It came up as a suggested edit to a tag wiki, and I rejected it. It is my opinion that the tag will be deleted - I am wondering if this is the general feeling in this community. @boboquack

Answer (score 4):

I also rejected this suggested edit.

We've had previous joke tags which haven't usually lasted long. I don't think [honeypot](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/honeypot) is going to be a useful tag, although something clearer with a similar meaning like [unsolvable](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unsolvable) ([insoluble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insoluble)?) might be.

Comment: It might also be a nice idea, in the spirit of not hating fun, to create a tag for puzzles which feature PSE community members. (We've had quite a few of these - I can think of seven just off the top of my head.) Not that this is an actual type of puzzle which needs a particular way of thinking to solve, but someone might still want to get a list and look at all these puzzles together just for fun, which would be easier with a tag.